# How can I make my view return the sum of a collection?

Tags: c#

I am trying to do this with the following code but it gives me many errors:

```
public abstract class BaseGridViewModel
{

    protected BaseGridViewModel()
    {
        Events = new List<ViewEvent>();
        Watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    }
    public SelectList Statuses { get; set; }
    public IList<ViewEvent> Events { get; set; }
    public string Topics { get; set; }
    public SelectList Types { get; set; }
    public string View { get; set; }
    public Stopwatch Watch { get; set; }

    public void Event(string description) {
        if (Watch.IsRunning) {
            Events.Add(new ViewEvent(description, Watch.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Watch not running");
        }
    }
    public long Elapsed {
        get { 
            return Events.Sum(event => event.Elapsed)
        }
    }

public class ViewEvent {

    public long Elapsed { get; private set; }
    public string Description { get; private set; }
    public string Message { get; private set; }
    public int Quantity { get; private set; }

    public ViewEvent(string description, long elapsedTime, int quantity = 0, string message = "") {
        this.Description = description; 
        this.Elapsed = elapsedTime;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
        this.Message = message;
    }

}
```

All 9 errors are for this line: "return Events.Sum(event => event.Elapsed)"

Is there something wrong with my syntax for this?

Comment: is Elapsed a "long" and will return "Sum()" a long?

Comment: @BvdVen I'd imagine "Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" x2, "Invalid expression term 'event'" x2, "Invalid expression term '=>'", ") expected", "; expected" x2 and "Invalid expression term ')'"

Answer (score 2):

`event` is a keyword, try `e => e.Elapsed`